# how to use List<myClass> from a user control client -- in a webservice in asp.net?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, web-services, gridview

In my sample project I have webform1 that contains a user control, and a webservice -- Service1.  The user control contains a gridview which I populate with 5 rows of test data (5 columns and using boundfields in the gridview per requirements) on app startup.  I also populate a list in the gridview rowdatabound event which would serve as a tooltip list for one of the gridview boundfields (the 2nd field/column).

In the webservice (Service1) I create a (dummy) list which emmulates the tooltip list in the user control in webform1.  This dummy list contains test data.  When the page loads, I use Jquery to load up the fake tooltips from the list in Service1.  I can then hover over cells in the gridview in column[1] and see these sample tooltips.  This all works fine.

What I need is to be able to use the tooltip list from the user control --use that list in Service1 webservice.  How can I accomplish this?   The entire sample project listed below:

--webform1 markup and call to user control

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="ws_JQueryAjax_sample.WebForm1" %>

<%@ Register TagPrefix="uc" TagName="ucWF" Src="ucWF1.ascx" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>WebForm1</title>  
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <uc:ucWF ID="ucWFa" runat="server"  />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

---

--user control markup and scripts

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ucWF1.ascx.cs" Inherits="ws_JQueryAjax_sample.ucWF1" %>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
       $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Service1.asmx/GetMyStuff_M",
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        data: {},
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            $('[id*=GridViewA] tr').each(function (n) {
                $(this).find("td:eq(1)").each(function () {
                    var titel = typeof (data.d[n - 1]) === 'undefined' ? "" : data.d[n - 1].firstN + "<br />" + data.d[n - 1].lastN;
                    $(this).tooltip({ title: $(this).addClass("colr-tooltip"), title: titel, html: true, placement: "bottom" });
                });
            });
        },
        error: function (err) {
            alert("ucWF2 -- error " + JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
            console.log("AJAX error in request: " + JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
        }
    });
});

</script>

<style type="text/css">
.colr-tooltip + .tooltip > .tooltip-inner
{
    width: 200px;
    max-width: 600px !important;
    background-color: gainsboro;
    color: blue;
    text-align: left;
    opacity: 1;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);  
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px black;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px black;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 2px black;   
}
</style>


<div>
   <asp:GridView ID="GridViewA" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDataBound="GridViewA_RowDataBound" ShowFooter="true" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="10">
      <Columns>
         <asp:BoundField DataField="itm0" HeaderText="itm0A" />                
         <asp:BoundField DataField="itm1" HeaderText="itm1B" />
         <asp:BoundField DataField="itm2" HeaderText="itm2C" />
         <asp:BoundField DataField="itm3" HeaderText="itm3D" />  
         <asp:BoundField DataField="itm4" HeaderText="itm4E" />  
      </Columns>
   </asp:GridView>
</div>
```

---

--user control code behind

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Drawing;

namespace ws_JQueryAjax_sample
{
    public partial class ucWF1 : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        stuffB1 ttl;
        public List<stuffB1> toolTipLst;        

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                toolTipLst = new List<stuffB1>();

                List<stuffA1> lstA = new List<stuffA1>()
               {
                   new stuffA1{itm0="a1", itm1="111", itm2="apple", itm3="anna smith", itm4="aaa"},
                   new stuffA1{itm0="b1", itm1="222", itm2="banana", itm3="charlie sheen", itm4="ccc"},
                   new stuffA1{itm0="c1", itm1="333", itm2="cow", itm3="charlie sheen", itm4="ccc"},
                   new stuffA1{itm0="d1", itm1="444", itm2="donut", itm3="danielle monet", itm4="ddd"},
                   new stuffA1{itm0="e1", itm1="555", itm2="egret", itm3="emelio esteban", itm4="eee"}
               };
               GridViewA.DataSource = lstA;
                GridViewA.DataBind();
            }
         }

        protected void GridViewA_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                e.Row.Cells[1].ForeColor = Color.Red;
                ttl = new stuffB1() {  firstN = e.Row.Cells[2].ToString(), lastN = e.Row.Cells[3].ToString() };                    
                toolTipLst.Add(ttl);
            }
        }
    }


    public class stuffA1
    {
        public string itm0 { get; set; }
        public string itm1 { get; set; }
        public string itm2 { get; set; }
        public string itm3 { get; set; }
        public string itm4 { get; set; }
    }

    public class stuffB1
    {
        public string firstN { get; set; }
        public string lastN { get; set; }       
    }   
}
```

---

--Service1 code behind

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;

namespace ws_JQueryAjax_sample
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for Service1
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        List<stuffC> lstX = new List<stuffC>() { 
            new stuffC{firstN="a1",lastN="b1" },
            new stuffC{firstN="a2",lastN = "b2"},
            new stuffC{firstN="a3",lastN="b3" },
            new stuffC{firstN="a4",lastN = "b4"},
            new stuffC{firstN="a5",lastN = "b5"}
        };


        [WebMethod()]
        public stuffC[] GetMyStuff_M()
        {
            return lstX.ToArray();
        }        
    }

    public class stuffC
    {
        public string firstN { get; set; }
        public string lastN { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Comment: Where it shows error. Update this line `$(this).tooltip({ title: titel, html: true, placement: "bottom" });` are you getting value in your variable named `titel`

Comment: titel is just a distinguishing name from the property title as in tooltip title.  This sample project works correctly (I had to make a few edits here after I posted it incase you ran the code).  What I need is to be able to use the list from the user control  -- use that list in the webservice because in the actual application the tooltip will contain 14 properties and will service 1100+ rows of data.